# how do I set Cache-Control header for Cloud Files with Fog

Tags: ruby, rackspace-cloud

I've tried various combinations of the following, but none worked

```
file = dir.files.create(
                        :key    => file_name,
                        :body   => io_obj,
                        :public => true,
                        'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 6).to_s}"
                                )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst I haven't tested this explicitly on Rackspace Cloud, this is what I have been using (successfully) for my S3 uploads with Fog:

```
file = dir.files.create({
  :key    => filename
  :body   => File.open(filename),
  :public => true,
  :metadata => {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}
})
```